# Webtest for binary content, how to?

Tags: visual-studio, checksum, webtest

Assume a web page that returns binary content:
http://localhost/website/Default.aspx?FileId=value

and we have some files with known Ids and checksums (i.e. MD5).
How it's possible to extract whole response and calculate it's check-sum via some visual studio webtest ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property on WebTest called ResponseBodyCaptureLimit.  By default only the first 1.5 MB are captured (although I noticed you said you were getting 50 MB which surprises me).  Perhaps you could try cranking this number up to hold 1 GB.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.webtest.responsebodycapturelimit(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I ended up writing my own test application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the property
this.Context.LastResponse.BodyBytes
after you yield the webtestrequest?

A custom validation rule may be the way to go to calculate that the hash matches the content.

Comment: Yes I did. My response is a huge file and this method just returns < 50 MB. I need abou 1 GB of response.

Comment: Sorry, I've got nothing. Perhaps it would be possible to override the correct part of a WebtestRequest and pull the full file a piece at a time, but I have not found anything using .Net Reflector that seems to be appropriate.